# Displaying 4 products per row instead of 3

Tags: magento

**Magneto 1.5**

Some default features in Magent just do not make any damn sense to me.
Take a look at the following image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7MbQ.png

Why would I want an empty column on every row? It looks so bad and from what I've been Googling it seems quite troublesome to fix. This of course being in the older versions, I cannot find anything for Magento 1.5

Could anyone explain to me how to fill out the columns nicely?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You can determine the column count through layout/catalog.xml

Find the line that looks like this:

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
```

Change the value of `<columns></columns>` to add/subtract columns.

Comment: There is no file called catalog.xml in the magento directory. I'm using Magento 1.5 if that's any help :/

Comment: `<catalog_category_default>
 <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product_list">
  <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action> <!-- 4 not 3 -->
 </reference>
</catalog_category_default>`

It will look something like this. The above code can be applied to your local.xml :)